# Jenkins Groovy pipeline @tmp dir() AccessDenied exception for createDirectory

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline, centos7

I'm trying to set-up a simple (single) Groovy pipeline script that would deploy my PHP project using webhooks. Sounds like a simple script and I've had it working in an older Jenkins version (which used bash script) but when I use the `dir(String) {}` method I get the following exception:

```
java.nio.file.AccessDeniedException: /srv/www/staging@tmp
    at sun.nio.fs.UnixException.translateToIOException(UnixException.java:84)
    at sun.nio.fs.UnixException.rethrowAsIOException(UnixException.java:102)
    at sun.nio.fs.UnixException.rethrowAsIOException(UnixException.java:107)
    at sun.nio.fs.UnixFileSystemProvider.createDirectory(UnixFileSystemProvider.java:384)
    at java.nio.file.Files.createDirectory(Files.java:674)
    at java.nio.file.Files.createAndCheckIsDirectory(Files.java:781)
    at java.nio.file.Files.createDirectories(Files.java:767)
    at hudson.FilePath.mkdirs(FilePath.java:3563)
```

The server itself runs on CentOS 7 and Jenkins is using version `2.303.3`. I've added the jenkins user to the `apache` group, which is the owner+group of the relative webroot, located in `/srv/www/staging`. The permissions for the `/srv/www` and `/srv/www/staging` directories are set to `0773 apache:apache`.

When I simulate a bash session with user `jenkins` using `su -s /bin/bash jenkins`, I am able to create directories and files within the `/srv/www/staging` directory - without any issue. So I'm wondering how the pipeline itself doesn't have permissions to do so!..

The pipeline script is as follows:

```
pipeline {
    agent any

    stages {
        stage('Git Pull') {
            steps {
                sh "whoami"
                dir ('/srv/www/staging') {
                    sh "pwd"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The `sh "whoami"` returns `jenkins`, so I'm sure the proper user is executing the commands.

I can't really find a descriptive similar issue, thus why I'm posting this.
Hopefully someone is able to guide me in the right direction.

Comment: Creating directories outside of the workspace on a Jenkins build agent is rather unusual. Could you clarify why you want to do this?

Comment: @MattSchuchard I've normally always set-up my web projects within the `/srv/www` directory. Is the error occuring because I'm going outside Jenkins' workspace scope? I could try to make a symbolic link to the `/srv/www` directory, or just moving the project the Jenkins workspace directory.

Comment: So I've changed the build to a "Freestyle Project" instead of a pipeline one, which grants me the ability to run bash scripts again instead of Groovy. I'll have to look into the proper way to use the Groovy pipelines at a later time..